# how to change coordinates x and y in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array I am putting a example here

My goal is to reverse the x-y corr of all the paris,

Please tell me how to do that?

x is coming from loop, and  every time i want to convert it into expected

```
input-:

x=[[1,2],[1,2],[1,4],[1,2],[3,2]]

expected
 =[[2,1],[2,1],[4,1],[2,1],[2,3]]
```

How can I get that result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should make your array nparray. Then you can use the [NumPy.flip](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html) function:

```
numpy.flip(m, axis=None)
```

Reverse the order of elements in an array along the given axis.

The shape of the array is preserved, but the elements are reordered.

It simply reverses the `nparray` with extra variable that defines the dimension of flipping. Your wanted dimension is 1:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 2], [3, 2]])
y = np.flip(x, 1)

print(x) #array([[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 2], [3, 2]])
print(y) #array([[2, 1], [2, 1], [4, 1], [2, 1], [2, 3]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example code does not use numpy. Here's how you could do it:

a) With a simple Python list comprehension

```py
x=[[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]]
y = [[element[1],element[0]] for element in x]
```

b) Using numpy to flip the array along `axis=1`:

```py
x = np.array([[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]])
y = np.flip(x, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension, you can reverse each pair.

The `-1` in `[::-1]` denotes a negative step (aka reverse).

```py
expected = [pair[::-1] for pair in x]
```

Comment: It is a really good and Python-native solution, but it is not using NumPy...

Comment: @EgorRandomize I would argue that their example did not utilize a numpy array for `x`. 